# Angular ngForm inside ng-template

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, angular-template

I have a form inside ng-template which is shown in a modal,

```
.ts
  @ViewChild('newControlForm', {static: false}) public newControlForm: NgForm;
.html
<ng-template>
    <form role="form" #newControlForm="ngForm">
</form>
</ng-template>
```

but since the form is inside ng-template its not able to get rendered that makes this.newControlForm to be undefined.

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem??

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-template` when you want to show something depending on some condition. See example

Instead of:

```
<div *ngIf="isDisplayed">Item 1</div>
<div *ngIf="!isDisplayed">Item 2</div>
```

You can do this:

```
<div *ngIf="isDisplayed; else showItem2">Item 1</div>

<ng-template #showItem2>
Item 2
</ng-template>
```

But in your case, you permanently want to show ngForm than why using ng-template, just use div